# ESP32にセキュアブートをかけたい

Tags: esp32

お世話になっております。

ESP32にプログラムを焼く際に、セキュアブートとフラッシュ暗号化をかけたいと思っています。

フラッシュ暗号化に関しては

１．キーの作成
python espsecure.py generate_flash_encryption??_key./mykey.bin
２．キーのefuseへの書き込み
python espefuse.py --port COM〇burn_key flash_encryption ./mykey.bin
BURN
３．idf.py menu.configで
Security Features内の[enable flash encription on boot(READ DOCS FIRST)]を有効
　　→[Enable Usage mode]を「Development」→「Release」
４．mkflash COM〇

でなんとかできたのですが、セキュアブートのやり方が分かりません。

下記サイトを参考にやりました。
http://dsas.blog.klab.org/archives/2018-09/52298778.html

セキュアブートのやり方をご教授願えませんでしょうか。

Comment: 「フラッシュ暗号化」の方は解決しているのであれば、質問は「セキュアブート」の話題に絞ったほうが分かりやすくなるんじゃないかと思いますがいかがでしょうか？

Comment: そうですね。訂正します。

Answer (score 0):

「Security Features」の「Enable hardware secure boot in bootloader」にチェックを付け、「Secure bootleader mode」を「Reflashable」にしたのち、
makeを実行
idf.py -p COM○ bootloader-flashを実行
idf.py -p COM○ flash を実行
でセキュアブートを付けることができました。
ありがとうございました。